# how to remove Property 'message' has no initializer error in ts without masking errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am creating a model in node js using ts and sequelize

```
import { Table, Column, Model, AllowNull } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
class Person extends Model {
  @Column
  @AllowNull(false)
  name: string;

  @Column
  birthday: Date;
}
```

But I am getting Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

I don't want to initialize it with an empty string. But I also don't want to add

```
strictPropertyInitialization": false
```

and mask the errors.

What is the correct way to work around?

Comment: you have set the `@AllowNull(false)` so it cannot be null, it has to have a value, you can probably make it an optional property to avoid giving it value. but if its gonna have a value of null, make it nullable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!` or `?` as follows:

```js
@Table
class Person extends Model {
  @Column
  @AllowNull(false)
  name!: string; // <---- Type: string

  @Column
  birthday?: Date; // <---- Type: Date | undefined
}
```

The `!` symbol is used to indicate that a property will never be undefined, meaning that if a value is not assigned to it, it will throw an error. On the other hand, the `?` symbol is used to indicate that a property can be undefined, meaning that if a value is not assigned to it, it will be considered undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In NestJs, using the @nestjs/common v10.0.0 (a new one on this date)

they use this config on their **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,   // <---- YOU WANT THIS
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

The rule "***strictNullChecks"*** says: *When type checking, take into account null and undefined.*

So, setting this rule to false, will fix this too.